# How to use only text fields that aren't null in java

Tags: java, sql

I'm making a project with a system and database in Java.
Some example code:

```
if(tfNamn != null) {
    try {
        idb.update("UPDATE ALIEN SET NAMN = " + "'" + nyttNamn + "'" + "WHERE ALIEN_ID = " + "'" + nyAlienID + "'");
    } catch (InfException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(AndraAlienInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When I do this the name changes in the database, however, I have other data as well such as password, race, etc. If I only change the name, the database will have a null value on the other text fields that have no user input, even if there is a password and a race already, these values become null. How do I stop empty textfield from changing the existing data to null?

Comment: Never ever build SQL statements by string concatenation. Use prepared statements instead. Your code is a prime example for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: An `UPDATE ALIEN SET NAMN = <name> WHERE ALIEN_ID = <id>` will not touch any other column than `namn`. There must be something else doing the changes. Be it your Java program executing some unexpected code paths or a trigger in the database or...